# JNI doesn't initialize Class Obj with String

Tags: string, object, constructor, java-native-interface

Below is my C and Java code. Java called `function1` to collect a `String` and an `integer` and return them using `ResultCollector` object. The `ResultCollector` is an outer class, in other words, it is not nested inside the `ResultCollecter` class. Also, it has three constructors. I have other functions that are fine with a constructor with `(IF)V` signature. Also, the third constructor is not working as well (i.e. `(II)V`).

Java code is:

```
package user.directory;
public class ResultCollector {
    private int err;
    private float resVal;
    private String resID;

/**
 * Signature (IF)V
 */
public ResultCollector(int err, float value) {
    this.err = err;

    this.resVal = value;
}

/**
 * Signature (II)V
 */
public ResultCollector(int err, int value) {
    this.err = err;

    this.resVal = (float) value;
}

/**
 * Signature (ILjava/lang/;)V
 */
public ResultCollector(int err, char[] id) {
    this.err = err;
    this.resID = String.copyValueOf(id);

}

public String id() {
    return resID;
}

public int err() {
    return err;
}

public float value() {
    return resVal;
}

public void setParam(int err, String id, float value) {
    this.err = err;
    this.resID = id;
    this.resVal = value;
}

}
```

And C code is:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_project_function1(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint index) {
    jint t;
    char *id = C function to return string; 
    t = an error that is needed;


     if (c == NULL)
         // throw exception
       return NULL;

     jstring name = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, id);

     if (name == NULL)
         // throw exception
       return NULL;

     jclass c = (*env)->FindClass(env,
        "user/directory/ResultCollector");
     jmethodID constr = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, c, "<init>", "(ILjava/lang/String;)V");

    if (constr == NULL)
    //cannot get the constructor correctly
       return NULL;

   jobject result = (*env)->NewObject(env, c, constr, t, name);
   return result;
}
```

My question is: How I can initialize an outer class? Where does it go wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1):

`char[]` is not the same as `String`. The signature for your constructor function should be `(I[C)V` (`[` indicates an array, `C` is for char):

```
jmethodID constr = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, c, "<init>", "(I[C)V");
```

You will also need to pass a `jcharArray` instead of a `jstring`. You can create the `jcharArray` like this:

```
int len = strlen(id);
jcharArray charArray = (*env)->NewCharArray(env, len);
(*env)->SetCharArrayRegion(env, charArray, 0, len, id);
```

Alternatively, you can change your Java code to accept a `String` instead of a `char[]`:

```
public ResultCollector(int err, String id) {
    this.err = err;
    this.resID = id;    
}
```

Comment: Moral: don't write JNI method signatures yourself. Use the output of `javap -s`. It is never wrong.

Comment: Thanks samgak! Different approaches were tried. I tried arraychar too. Your approach didn't work for me, even though I have to admit that your answer is totally correct! The problem is JNI recognize one of the constructors at a time. So, I ended up defining three classes for each result. Now, it is working. I am not sure why JNI is unhappy with several constructors.